# Is there a C++ decompiler?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I have a program in which I've lost the C++ source code.  Are there any good C++ decompilers out there?

I've already ran across [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: `objdump` for Linux

Comment: https://cutter.re/ for great gui and great builtin decompiler

Comment: Are there any decompilers in 2022?

Comment: [Decompiler explorer](https://dogbolt.org/) doesn't require to download anything

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) by [Hex-Rays](http://www.hex-rays.com/). You will usually not get good C++ out of a binary unless you compiled in debugging information. Prepare to spend a **lot** of manual labor reversing the code.

If you didn't strip the binaries there is some hope as IDA Pro can produce C-alike code for you to work with. Usually it is very rough though, at least when I used it a couple of years ago.

Comment: To clarify, IDA will only give the disassembly. There's an add-on to it called Hex-Rays that will decompile the rest of the way into C/C++ source, to the extent that's possible.

Comment: To my reading of the docs, hex-rays only outputs C like pseudo-code. Not that that makes it useless for decompilling C++, you just need to know a bit about how compilers convert C++ structures.

Comment: To Clarify Some more, Disassembly is the most you can decompile with Hex-Rays will translate ASM to C++ ASM can be translated to any programming language with work as all programs can run as ASM

Comment: Note that even the earliest release of the [Hex-Rays plugin](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml) is not compatible with the [IDA 5.0 Freeware](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) release of IDA.

Comment: SNOWMAN is a good free c++ decompiler

Comment: +1 for Snowman, but as others have mentioned, even a simple [Hello, World](https://derevenets.com/examples.html#_hello_world) becomes practically unreadable once decompiled.

Answer (score 29):

information is discarded in the compiling process.  Even if a decompiler could produce the logical equivalent code with classes and everything (it probably can't), the self-documenting part is gone in optimized release code.  No variable names, no routine names, no class names - just addresses.

Comment: "the soul" of the program is gone, just an empty shell of it's former self..."

Answer (score 21):

Yes, but none of them will manage to produce readable enough code to worth the effort. You will spend more time trying to read the decompiled source with assembler blocks inside, than rewriting your old app from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't seen any decompilers that generate C++ code. I've seen a few experimental ones that make a reasonable attempt at generating C code, but they tended to be dependent on matching the code-generation patterns of a particular compiler (that may have changed, it's been awhile since I last looked into this). Of course any symbolic information will be gone. Google for "decompiler".

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how large and how well-written the original code was, it might be worth starting again in your favourite language (which might still be C++) and learning from any mistakes made in the last version. Didn't someone once say about writing one to throw away?

n.b. Clearly if this is a huge product, then it may not be worth the time.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Comment: Joel is a great columnist, but at times wrong. And then there are times when he's quoted wrong. Like here, since the question centers around the loss of source code. Joels article explains why source code is valuable.

Comment: *Didn't someone once say about writing one to throw away?* Yeah, and he changed his mind http://www.davewsmith.com/blog/2010/brook-revisits-plan-to-throw-one-away *[I]n 1975, I counseled programmers to “throw the first version away,” then build a second one. By the 20th-anniversary edition, I realized that constant incremental iteration is a far sounder approach*