# EXE extraction / decompiler

Tags: exe, extract

I have tried a few EXE extractor but they don't work on a lot of files. I am looking for something better.

Comment: If you thought "EXE extractor" was a technical term, you're wrong.

Comment: What have you tried? What language do you want to decompile to? C? C++? By teh way, the correct term for "exe extractor" is "decompiler".

Answer (score 4):

What kind of .exe? Win32 / DOS / .NET?

- If .NET, you should use **Reflector** (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
- If Win32 and C++, you can try decompilers posted here ([Is there a C++ decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205059/is-there-a-c-decompiler))

There are a lot's of extractors/decompilers on the market, so you should say more explicitly what is your goal (ie. to extract images, decompile assembly source etc.)

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way just download a zip view like winrar winzip and open the .exe with that it will show you all the components

Comment: This does not work for all exe files.