# How to view the source code of a Silverlight dll

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, reverse-engineering

I have a DLL of the Silverlight 4  Datagrid control. How can I see the source code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: JetBrains *dotpeek* is great! also it is free. [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Reflector tool which is a Red Gate Product.
Check out: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 1):

Use reflector tool for .net

Answer (score 0):

You mean reverse compiling code?  You'll have to be mindful of the law when doing all types of decompiling, but tools like Ada PRO will help you do that.

Keep in mind when you decompile code, you're going to get assembly code that you'll have to further decompile (sometimes by hand) into something like C or C++.

Good recommendation here: [Is there a C++ decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205059/is-there-a-c-decompiler)