# Decompiling Delphi Programs

Tags: delphi, reverse-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi decompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130078/delphi-decompiling)

I want to decompile a Delphi 5 application to .pas format, Is there any application that do this with ease? I want to insert my app and it gives me .pas with ease.

Any help is really appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: Cannot be done, you can disassemble but not decompile.

Comment: Where did this .exe come from?

Comment: @ David What do you mean? I think you know that I have an exe which is written is Delphi in years ago, one of my friend had written it for me, now there is no project file, and I want to give it some changes, so I need the sources if possible, so possible?

Comment: I suspected that on the basis of your previous questions. I just want to clear it up for all the other potential answerers.  So you have just an exe file and no source files whatsoever.

Comment: Use Interactive Delphi Reconstructor IDR