# Where can i find the "pywrap_calibration.so" file beacuse it also doesnt exist in the source repository

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have been building custom tensorflow for my machine but after running the command to buid the pip package

```
./bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package --nightly_flag /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

as gotten from the tensorflow documentaion  I get this error

```
chmod: cannot access '/tmp/tmp.nD2R58B8Yp/tensorflow/compiler/mlir/quantization/tensorflow/calibrator/pywrap_calibration.so': No such file or directory
```

i have searched the source directory for "pywrap_calibration.so" but i only find "pywrap_calibartion.pyi" and "pywrap_calibration.cc"

I dont know what to do next

Comment: Maybe this helps a bit? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9810368/15019223. Seems that something went wrong at copilation time.